Could not determine the dependencies of task ':flutter_compass:compileDebugAidl'. > Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-30
I need to add a time signature in my application, but I ended up with this error.
I used the package: flutter_compass: ^0.8.0
I can't build my application because of this error.
enter image description here
I've tried changing the build.gradle, but nothing changes.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

use platform android-30 and install the api level 30 in android studio.
Step 1: Open Preferences or Settings in Android studio. Select Android SDK options and Install Android API 30 as selected below.maybe after that you get complieSDK issue in you app/gradle. if you get issue just update it to demanded compileSDK version. also share your app/build.gradle file for better help
